# JS SDK current language

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Is it possible to get the current language with JS SDK in a canvas app? If yes, how?

I'm trying to get it in order to set the correct language in the app even if the user changes it from the bottom menu.

Answer (score 1):

There is a value in the signed request;

```
$signed_request['user']['locale']
```

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/

Another way is to get it with graph api:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=locale
```

Comment: I need it through the JS SDK not PHP SDK.

Comment: I searched a bit and seems it's not possible to get it without getting user authorization first :(

Comment: You can get the signed_request via the js sdk. When you call getLoginStatus() it is part of the authResponse object. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/ for more information.